# Spring Boot validation with jakarta.validation doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have some problems with validations in Spring Boot 3.
I have 21 fields in 6 Entities that have validations with import jakarta.validation but of these, only 2 with @NotBlank work and return in the Thymeleaf view the message I set.

All 6 fields of type LocalDateTime with @Future trigger the error in the view but do not print the message I set in the annotation.
All other fields do not throw any error in the view.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.la7.travel</groupId>
    <artifactId>la7-travel</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>la7-travel</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Validator spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>6.0.13.Final</version>-->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- font-awesome -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Vue.js -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>vue</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0-alpha.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This throws the error and prints the error-message I set in the annotation

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Future;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class Ticket{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 100, message = "Max 100 characters")
    @NotBlank(message = "Field required")
    @Column(nullable=false, length=100)
    private String placeDeparture;
```

This throws the error in the view but do not print the error-message I set in the annotation

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Future;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class CarRental{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Future(message="Future Date required")
    @Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private LocalDateTime dateTimeRedelivery;
```

This doesn't throws any error in the view

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Future;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
public class CarRental{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Size(max = 100, message = "Max 100 characters")
    @NotBlank(message = "Field required")
    @Column(nullable=false, length=100)
    private String placePickup;
```

Comment: Show the view, show the controller, show your configuration. Also stating "this doesn't work" isn't really helpful, what doesn't work?